# selenium 2.0 webdriver tests compilation errors

Tags: java, maven, selenium-webdriver

No matter which Selenium 2.xx version web-drivers I use, I get the same compilation errors

> : error reading C:\Documents and
>   Settings\kondojis.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\2.0b3\selenium-firefox-driver-2.0b3.jar;
>   error in opening zip file

This is what I have in my POM file

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium</artifactId>
    <version>2.0rc2</version>
    <type>pom</type>  <i tried with and without type pom>
</dependency>
```

I am using jdk 1.6, Maven 3.0.1 M am using Maven compiler plugin 2.3.2 etc on Windows XP

```
package com.usps.mgo.icoa.UI;

import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.is;
import static org.hamcrest.CoreMatchers.not;
import static org.junit.Assert.assertThat;

import org.junit.After;
import org.junit.Before;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource;

import javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicInternalFrameTitlePane;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

/**
 * Created by IntelliJ IDEA.
 * User: kondojis
 * Date: 2/8/11
 * Time: 5:02 PM
 * To change this template use File | Settings | File Templates.
 */
public class SimulatorTests {
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(SimulatorTests.class);
    private static WebDriver driver;
    private ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource messageSource;
    private static ClassPathXmlApplicationContext springCtx;

    /**
     * Properties for Simulator tests
     */

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        // Bootstrap Spring Framework.
        springCtx = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext(
                new String[]{"test-config.xml"});
        //Make Sure that test_global.properties file is always in sync with the global.properties file from production.
        messageSource = springCtx.getBean("messageSource", ReloadableResourceBundleMessageSource.class);
        driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Error in opening zip file sounds like a corrupted jar in your local repo.  Try deleting the "C:\Documents and Settings\kondojis.m2\repository\org\seleniumhq\selenium\selenium-firefox-driver\" directory and making maven re-download it.

edit: Noticed your selenium dependency and error output have different versions, I declare a manual dependency like

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.0rc2</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: I tried deleting the folders and let maven download again. Same result. I tried all versions above 2 and i run into same situation. Yes there is discrepancy in version label in the code i added above, but in my code its all aligned and taken care off correctly though.
The older versions 0.6.1039  and 0.9.7376 were working fine until firefox was upgraded to latest and greatest and all hellp broke with profiles.